# More concise way to rotate the digits of a number in J

Tags: j

I've written a relatively simple verb to rotate the digits of a number (in the manner required by Project Euler #35). So, if I start with 197 I'll get 197 971 719, i.e., the first digit is made last until we get back where we started.

Here's my verb: `".@(|.~"1 0 i.@#)@":"0`. (Actually, mine takes it a step further and adds `~.` to remove dupes, but that's not necessary.) Is there a more concise way to do this in J?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not shorter but I find it more concise in a way:

```
v =: 1&|.^:(<@#)&.":
v 1234
1234 2341 3412 4123
v 197
197 971 719
```

It uses `^:` (power) of 1-shift `1&|.` instead of a variable shift and `&.` (under) to convert from integer to string and back.

Comment: I keep forgetting about `&.`. Extremely useful. Of course you still need to know the obverse, but in many cases it's obvious.

Comment: This answer is more idiomatic J than mine, which is really what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach is to make the formatted number into a matrix with n rows of n+1 digits where n is the number of digits, then drop the last column.

```
   v=. }:"1@($~(,>:)@#)&.": 
   v 1234
1234 2341 3412 4123
   v 197
197 971 719
```

In this form it uses 2 hooks which is always a bit of fun to figure out.
`(,>:)` adds one and appends to the argument
`($~(,>:)@#)` takes the formatted number and shapes it to a n,n+1 matrix.
Also note that it does not use `|.` (Rotate)